# UISearchController in TableView header overlaps other items

Tags: ios, swift

Even though I have correct constraints set up for the top label and button so the TableView does not overlap, when expanding the SearchBar it overlaps still top and right of screen.

The `SearchBar` of `UISearchController` is added as the header of the `TableView`.

[image: Image showing the problem]

Code for generating the UISearchController and TableView

```
//Create our search controller
self._searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self._searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
self._searchController?.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self._searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for products or activities"
self._searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self._searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
self._searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.colorPrimary()
self._searchController?.searchBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
self._searchController?.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Products", "Activities"]
self._searchController?.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0
self._searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
self.definesPresentationContext = true

//Prepare our tableView
self._tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
self._tableView.separatorStyle = .none
self._tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
self._tableView.delegate = self
self._tableView.dataSource = self
self._tableView.register(ProductViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ProductViewCell.identifier)
self._tableView.register(ActivityViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ActivityViewCell.identifier)
self._tableView.tableHeaderView = self._searchController?.searchBar
```

I tried hiding the content at the top when the `SearchBar` is active with the following

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //self._titleLabel.fadeOut(0.0)
    //self._barCodeButton.fadeOut(0.0)
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //self._titleLabel.fadeIn(1.0)
    //self._barCodeButton.fadeIn(1.0)
}
```

But if I want to defocus the `SearchBar` when scrolling the table with with

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self._searchController?.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

the SearchBar will stay, items will fade in and it will all overlap again.

Comment: Can you post the sourcecode?

Comment: I added all code related to the searchbar. Is there anything else?

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I don't want the search bar in the top navigation.

Comment: I think you need to set frame of tableview

Answer (score 0):

The default option for the UISearchController on iOS11+ is to hide the navigation bar and move the search bar up (with animation) when searching.

I think for your case you just need to turn this off:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: That just seemed to push it up further. I don't have a navigation bar, the label and button are just on the view like everything else. https://i.imgur.com/kfQxbZB.png

Comment: thats strange, i've just used this code this morning stop it animating up. How come your building the 'navigation bar' manually instead of using an actual navigation bar and large titles? support for ios10?